# Trouble creating custom folders in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, directory, organization

I am have a lot of trouble with CodeBlocks currently that is leaving me really frustrated.  Basically, all I want to do is create my own folders within code blocks, and move my files into them.

Currently I am using default settings which forces file types into their own kind of virtual folder.  I have a Sources folder with all of my .cpp files, and a Headers folder with all of my .h folders.  All I want is a traditional layout.

For example, it is currently impossible for me to create a folder called Input which has both my input cpp and h files.  While I looked online, I found an example where someone had [this set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKqxU.png) which has actual folders, where [this is my current set up.](http://image.prntscr.com/image/d101b1fd8fed4371a33df3e4757c5e9d.png)  Sources and Headers only exists in editor, and not in my actual folders.  Do you have any idea how to fix this?  I am trying to follow some tutorials that require the creation of folders : /

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just create the new folders in explorer?

Comment: Make the folders outside of CodeBlocks, then in your cb project, add files from where they are.  (You may need to manually configure includes directory if the headers are in a different location)

Comment: I can create folders out of codeblocks, but they dont show in the editor : /  The rest feels like a bandaid fix